# Roles / Permissions to create EMR Cluster using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr, aws-cli

I am trying to create a cluster using aws emr command. To call out initially I dont have admin role to do most of the stuff.

```
aws emr create-cluster --release-label emr-4.2.0  --instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m3.xlarge InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=2,InstanceType=m3.xlarge --service-role MY_ROLE--ec2-attributes KeyName=MY_KEY_PAIR,SubnetId=subnet-xxxxxxxx,InstanceProfile=MY_ROLE
```

I am trying to run this command on a EC2 instance. I immediately get a success message with Cluster Id displayed. However the machine terminates with invalid role error message.

If I try to see the cluster state in AWS console then I see so many permission error messages.

Are there set of permissions required by a role / policies which will ensure creation of a cluster with out any error ?

I cant use --use-default-role as I don't have permission to create a role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you the `EMR_DefaultRole` that I'm using to create the emr with:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
            "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
            "ec2:CancelSpotInstanceRequests",
            "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
            "ec2:CreateTags",
            "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
            "ec2:DeleteTags",
            "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
            "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
            "ec2:DescribeDhcpOptions",
            "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
            "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
            "ec2:DescribeNetworkAcls",
            "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
            "ec2:DescribePrefixLists",
            "ec2:DescribeRouteTables",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "ec2:DescribeSpotInstanceRequests",
            "ec2:DescribeSpotPriceHistory",
            "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcAttribute",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpoints",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointServices",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
            "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:ModifyImageAttribute",
            "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute",
            "ec2:RequestSpotInstances",
            "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
            "ec2:RunInstances",
            "ec2:TerminateInstances",
            "iam:GetRole",
            "iam:GetRolePolicy",
            "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
            "iam:ListRolePolicies",
            "iam:PassRole",
            "s3:CreateBucket",
            "s3:Get*",
            "s3:List*",
            "sdb:BatchPutAttributes",
            "sdb:Select",
            "sqs:CreateQueue",
            "sqs:Delete*",
            "sqs:GetQueue*",
            "sqs:PurgeQueue",
            "sqs:ReceiveMessage"
        ]
    }]
}
```

And also, the EC2 default profile role `EMR_EC2_DefaultRole`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Action": [
            "cloudwatch:*",
            "dynamodb:*",
            "ec2:Describe*",
            "elasticmapreduce:Describe*",
            "elasticmapreduce:ListBootstrapActions",
            "elasticmapreduce:ListClusters",
            "elasticmapreduce:ListInstanceGroups",
            "elasticmapreduce:ListInstances",
            "elasticmapreduce:ListSteps",
            "kinesis:CreateStream",
            "kinesis:DeleteStream",
            "kinesis:DescribeStream",
            "kinesis:GetRecords",
            "kinesis:GetShardIterator",
            "kinesis:MergeShards",
            "kinesis:PutRecord",
            "kinesis:SplitShard",
            "rds:Describe*",
            "s3:*",
            "sdb:*",
            "sns:*",
            "sqs:*"
        ]
    }]
}
```

Comment: I see this is what we get as default if we use --use-defualt-role ?? Some of these permissions may not be needed right ??? or all of them are needed for sure ???

Comment: This is the default role you're getting when using `--use-default-role`. I'm not sure all of these permissions needed, that's depends on how you configured your EMR. For example: use CloudWatch for monitoring? or not? so it basically up to you.

Comment: Thank you. Will figure out what all options I actually need.